# Using SQL in VB.Net connecting to Access Database

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I'm using Access as a backing data store (I know why not use MySQL right?). Anyway, getting over that, I want to use SQL to search for a booking date on my database. I can get it to look up todays date but I'd like some way of typing in a date and then finding results based on this. My code so far is this:

```
Public Class Bookings
    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim dbProvider As String
    Dim dbSource As String
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim sql As String


    Private Sub Bookings_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OleDB.4.0;"
        dbSource = "Data Source = C:\Users\wm\Desktop\MAdams\Karting2000DB.mdb"

        con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource

        con.Open()

        sql = "SELECT * FROM tblBookings WHERE BookingDate = txtDate.Text"

        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
        da.Fill(ds, "AddressBook")

        MsgBox("Database is now open")

        con.Close()

        MsgBox("Database is now closed")

        txtBookingNumber.Text = ds.Tables("AddressBook").Rows(0).Item("ID")
        txtCustID.Text = ds.Tables("AddressBook").Rows(0).Item("CustomerID")
    End Sub     
End Class
```

I'm pretty new to this so simpler the better!

Many thanks

Comment: the dbConnection object and DataAdpater  should not be reused.  Create and dispose of them as needed to release the resources they use.  That is also a bad way to specify the DBfile location.  Use `Path.Combine` and `Environment.GetFolderPath`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't embed the text property of your `txtDate` textbox inside the sql string and hope that it is translated to the correct value.

You need to use a parameterized query

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM tblBookings WHERE BookingDate = @date"
da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@date", OleDbType.Date).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.Text)
da.Fill(ds, "AddressBook")
```

This approach requires that your user types a valid date inside the textbox. If you are unsure if the date is correct then you need to use a TryParse method to extract a valid datetime object from your text

```
Dim bookDate as DateTime
if Not DateTime.TryParse(txtDate.Text, bookDate) then
    MessageBox.Show("Not a valid date")
else
    ..... the code above with the bookDate passed as parameter value.
```

As @Plutonix said in its comment there are a lot of best practices that need to be applied to your code

- Do not implement global variables for the connection, adapter and
  other managed classes. They need to be fred immediately after usage
  and rebuilt when you need them again
- Objects like the connection, adapters and eventually the DataReader
  implements the disposable interface. This means that you should
  enclose them in the Using statement to destroy them when you don't
  need them anymore
- Do not hard code the connectionstring in your methods. If you want to
  distribute your application you need to change that string everywhere
  (unless your target pc has the same path) Use the app.Config
  (web.Config) and the ConfigurationManager class to retrieve it

Comment: Fab thanks I have it working now. I know its no perfect and it needs tidying up but I will make the changes you have suggested.

Comment: Also, if I wanted to search for a surname from a text box on a customer form what would the sql be? I'm really new to all this so any help is massively appreciated

Comment: It is just a matter to change the WHERE condition. Where is followed by a field name, an operator and a value. In your case, the field name is the surname field as spelled in the database table, the operator could be the = sign or LIKE and the value is a different placeholder for a parameter like you have now for the date field. See here introductory info on  the [WHERE clause](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp)

Comment: No, look at my answer. @surname in the query text is just a placeholder, the real parameter need to be added to the SelectCommand parameter collection. And please do not post an ANSWER, you could always edit your original question with more details albeit this seems to be a new question.

Comment: Really sorry, as I said I'm new to this. As it is I've got the Surname search working, thanks for the help. Here is what I did:sql = "SELECT * FROM tblContacts WHERE Surname = @Surname"

        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", txtSurname.Text)
        da.Fill(ds, "AddressBook")

Comment: Thanks Steve, your answer has been ticked.